# Add metabox if there is at least one post available

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am building a WordPress Dashboard widget which will showcase all posts & pages where a Gutenberg Block is active.

The below code does it's job and pulls in an array based on `get_posts()`.

**Here is what I'm attempting to do**:

1. Is there a way that I can invoke the `add_action` and the `pardot_dashboard_widget()` function **ONLY** if there is at least one or more posts in `get_posts()`? If it's an empty array, don't even bother creating the metabox.

**Here is the code**:

```
/**
 * Pardot Widget for Dashboard
 */
function pardot_dashboard_widget()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'pardot_dashboard_meta_box',
        esc_html__( 'Pardot Form Locations', 'wporg' ),
        'pardot_dashboard_stats',
        'dashboard',
        'side', 'high'
    );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'pardot_dashboard_widget');

function pardot_dashboard_stats()
{
    $args = [
        's'         => '<!-- wp:acf/pardot-form ',
        'sentence'  => 1,
        'post_type' => [
            'post',
            'page'
        ],
    ];
    $pardot_form_query = get_posts($args);
    if (!$pardot_form_query) {
       echo 'There are no active pardot forms available.';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try assigning the meta to a variable, and using that in the if statement.

For example:

```
   <?php
      $price_list = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price_list_category1', true );
 ?>
```

And then...

```
<?php
      if ($price_list == '') {
            echo '&nbsp;';
        } else {
            echo '<h2>' . add your meta box conditions here . '</h2>';
          }
    ?>
```